# WPF Stock Ticker/Animate item within ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a user control similar to a stock ticker.  It will slowly scroll the items to the left.  So far I am unable to get something going because:

- I am new to WPF/XAML and everywhere I search seems to apply to
  silvelight
- I am using an ItemTemplate within a ItemsControl, and cant find any
  examples showing how to add a storyboard for a item within an item template.

here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.Ctrls.MessageTicker"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Ctrls"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Background="Honeydew">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="_items">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="_panel">
                    <Grid.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="_panel"
                        From="0"
                        To="360"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Grid.Triggers>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Word}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Percent}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,3,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI Mono" Foreground="Blue"/>
                    <Polygon Points="0,10 5,0 10,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Green" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,3,10,0"/>
                    <Polygon Points="5,10 10,0 0,0" Stroke="Black" Fill="Red" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

From what I have read, I should be putting the storyboard within the template.  When I add a new item to the ItemsControl, nothing happens.  I need to have it start at the end of the ItemsControl and scroll to the right all the way to the beginning of the ItemsControl.

Comment: Don't sweat the Silverlight difference, WPF Xaml is the more robust of the two. I would worry more about WPF to Silverlight. I wouldn't be surprised if you couldn't take the Silverlight examples almost verbatim sans namespace differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you're close, but you're missing some key things that might explain why it's not firing as you'd expect.

So your first issue lies with how you're using _panel. We'll want to actually move that to an RenderTransform on this Grid that's acting as your parent.

So instead of;

```
<Grid x:Name="_panel">
```

We'll say;

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RenderTransform>
     <TranslateTransform x:Name="_panel">
   </Grid.RenderTransform>
...
```

Because your `TargetProperty` setting in your storyboard isn't going to magically append that Transform on demand like it looks you're thinking it might (at least I've never seen it done that way I don't think).

So we have that, now let's go talk to that Transform via your `Storyboard` and have it talk to **an actual property** of your Transform thusly;

```
<Storyboard>
   <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="_panel">
       <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="360" />
   </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

So what we're doing is basically saying "HEY _panel, guess what? You get to animate, and before you start I want you to know you're moving 360 across your X axis"

We could add a keytime here to make this happen over more keyframes to allow it to fill in the blanks of an actual animation sequence (your ticker anime, hint hint) but for now, we're just telling that bugger to move.

Other than that, you should work. Hope this helps, cheers.

Oh and PS, you'd be surprised how much XAML can work between WPF/SL/WP, etc. etc. if you just know the fundamentals. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Chris!  That works for the parent grid of the ctrl, but how can I trigger this animation per item?  I was thinking more along the lines that the parent Grid would be static, and as I add items to the ItemsControl, the new items would scroll.

Comment: Ah ok, so you want it to do something every time you add a new item? I would look at FluidMoveBehavior as an easy way to accomplish that. Except I'm a little confused, since as it sits, I would think it would animate each new grid when loaded unless you had like virtualizationmode on or something.